# jQuery UI effect 'explode' not working properly in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery-1.7.1.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js
my code fragment is

```
$(closeButton).click(function(){
    $( alertBox).hide("explode"); 
    $(alertWrapper).fadeOut(500);
    $(alertBox).remove();
    $(alertWrapper).remove();
});
```

getting some weird behavior in IE8 but its working fine in IE7 and all other browsers

The 'explode' effects is getting slow and after when the DIV element is dividing into 6 parts its not fading out in IE 8 I have checked its thrice...

Any help from your side will greatly appreciated...

Thanks in Advance.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dilse_arnab/R9dsq)

Comment: i did not understand your question  @ D3mon-1stVFW

Comment: Can you post a small sample of application in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: you can check my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dilse_arnab/R9dsq/